# Dynamically created tablewidget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a function that dynamically creates a stackedWidget and adds new pages based on a query. Each page gets a dynamically created tableWidget that is loaded before the code loops again. The stackedWidget is controlled by a List that is filled at the same time that each page is created. Up to this point, everything works great but I am having a problem extracting data from the tableWidgets. At the end of the loops there is a signal

```
ui.tableWidget.cellChanged[int,int].connect(saveLineItem)
```

that I used for testing. The function saveLineItem will print the row & column from whichever tableWidget is clicked on, but the last line, to print the text, will only print from the last tableWidget created. Obviously the signal recognizes the current tableWidget. How can I pass that on to the saveLineItem function?

```
    def saveLineItem(row, col): 
       print('row = ' + str(row))
       print('column = ' + str(col))
       ui = uiDef.ui
       print(ui.tableWidget.item(row, col).text())

    def loadInventory(ui):
            conn = sqlite3.connect('DbLocal.sqlite')
            cur = conn.cursor() 
            SQL = "SELECT INVENTORY.Inventory FROM INVENTORY WHERE Description = '*' ORDER BY Display_No"
            cur.execute(SQL)
            rows = cur.fetchall()

            if ui.swInventory:
                ui.swInventory.close()
            ui.lstCatagory.clear()
            ui.swInventory = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(ui.tab_Inventory)
            ui.swInventory.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(255, 20, 876, 586))
            ui.swInventory.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
            ui.swInventory.setObjectName("swInventory")
            lstInvHeader = ['Display_No','ITEM_NO', 'Trigger', 'Quantity', 'Description', 'Part_No', 'Price', 'Inventory', 'Spreadsheet', 'NoDisplay', 'T_S', 'Track', 'Msg', 'S_Hooks', 'P_Hooks' ]
            for row in rows:
                sCatName = row[0]
                page = sCatName
                ui.lstCatagory.addItem(sCatName)
                ui.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
                ui.page.setObjectName(sCatName)
                ui.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(ui.page)
                ui.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 831, 561))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setPointSize(14)
                ui.tableWidget.setFont(font)
                ui.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)        
                ui.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
                ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
                ui.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)

                ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(15)
                ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(lstInvHeader)
                ui.tableWidget.hideColumn(0)
                ui.tableWidget.hideColumn(1)
                ui.tableWidget.hideColumn(2)
                ui.tableWidget.hideColumn(5)
                ui.tableWidget.hideColumn(7)
                ui.tableWidget.hideColumn(8)
                ui.tableWidget.hideColumn(9)
                ui.tableWidget.hideColumn(10)
                ui.tableWidget.hideColumn(11)
                ui.tableWidget.hideColumn(12)
                ui.tableWidget.hideColumn(13)
                ui.tableWidget.hideColumn(14)
                ui.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(4, 611)

                SQL = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY WHERE Inventory = '{}' ORDER BY Display_No".format(sCatName)
                cur.execute(SQL)
                InvRows = cur.fetchall()
                i = 0
                for row in InvRows:
                    if row[4] == '*':
                        pass
                    else:
                        rDisplay_No = str(row[0])
                        iITEM_NO = str(row[1])
                        iTRIGGER = str(row[2])
                        iQUANTITY = ""
                        if row[3] == None:
                            iQUANTITY = ""
                        else:
                            #iQUANTITY = round(row[6], 2)               
                            iQUANTITY = str(iQUANTITY)
                        sDESCRIPTION = " " + str(row[4])
                        sPART_NO = row[5]
                        rPRICE = str(row[6])
                        sINVENTORY = row[7]
                        sSPREADSHEET = row[8]
                        iNoDisplay = str(row[9])
                        iT_S = str(row[10])
                        iTRACK = str(row[11])
                        iMSG = str(row[12])
                        iS_HOOKS = str(row[13])
                        iP_HOOKS = str(row[14])

                        item = QTableWidgetItem(rDisplay_No)
                        item2 =  QTableWidgetItem(iITEM_NO)
                        item3 =  QTableWidgetItem(iTRIGGER)
                        item4 = QTableWidgetItem(iQUANTITY)
                        item5 =  QTableWidgetItem(sDESCRIPTION)
                        item6 =  QTableWidgetItem(sPART_NO)
                        item7 = QTableWidgetItem(rPRICE)
                        item8 =  QTableWidgetItem(sINVENTORY)
                        item9 =  QTableWidgetItem(sSPREADSHEET)
                        item10 = QTableWidgetItem(iNoDisplay)
                         item11 =  QTableWidgetItem(iT_S)
                        item12 =  QTableWidgetItem(iTRACK)
                        item13 = QTableWidgetItem(iMSG)
                        item14 =  QTableWidgetItem(iS_HOOKS)
                        item15 =  QTableWidgetItem(iP_HOOKS)

                        item4.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                        item5.setFlags( Qt.NoItemFlags | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                        item7.setFlags( Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)

                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,0, item)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,1, item2)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,2, item3)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,3, item4)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,4, item5)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,5, item6)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,6, item7)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,7, item8)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,8, item9)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,9, item10)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,10, item11)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,11, item12)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,12, item13)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,13, item14)
                        ui.tableWidget.setItem(i,14, item15)
                        i += 1
                        ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(i+2)

                setattr(uiDef, "ui", ui)    
                ui.tableWidget.cellChanged[int,int].connect(saveLineItem)
                ui.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(ui.page)
                ui.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(308, 0, 151, 20))
                ui.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                ui.label.setObjectName("label")
                ui.label.setText(sCatName)
                ui.swInventory.addWidget(ui.page)
            iNumPages = ui.swInventory.count()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to solve this kind of problem is to connect the signal to a `lambda` (or partial function) that caches a reference to the current object:

```
def saveLineItem(table, row, col):
   print('row = ' + str(row))
   print('column = ' + str(col))
   print(table.item(row, col).text())

def loadInventory(ui):
    ...
    ui.tableWidget.cellChanged[int,int].connect(
        lambda row, colum, table=ui.tableWidget:
            saveLineItem(table, row, column))
```

Comment: saveLineItem() is called by the signal:     ui.tableWidget.cellChanged[int,int].connect(saveLineItem) and it doesn't have a table argument so how would that work?

Comment: My comment was not clear. When I was originally setting this up, I tried adding (row, col) arguments "ui.tableWidget.cellChanged[int,int].connect(saveLineItem(row, col)) but it wouldn't accept any arguments. That didn't make any sense to me, but removing the arguments allowed it to print the row and column.  I will try this. Thanks @ekhumoro